# XHR / Post Request using D3

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, d3.js, data-visualization

I was doing a research on how to make POST requests using the amazingly powerful [D3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3) (which I can fully fully recommend for data visualization) and found the [xhr2 branch](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/tree/xhr2) where the authors of D3 are currently working on xhr POST request (and other request types) support.

Seems like it is a brand new feature as the merge request is from yesterday (18 September 2012) :) And as curious I am I already wanted to try it out, using the following code sequence (which I have from this [location](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/811#issuecomment-8661257))

```
 d3.text("localhost/test",function(d) { console.log(d)})
         .method("POST")
         .setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
         .data("a=1&b=2&c=3");
```

Unfortunately I'm getting the following error message.

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating
>   'd3.text("localhost/test",function(d) { console.log(d)})
>                .method("POST")')

I'm using the [minified D3 version](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/xhr2/d3.v2.min.js) from the xhr2 branch. Anybody an idea what to change?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The API is still under development. If you want to try it out, the current API is like so:

```
d3.text("/test")
    .header("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    .post("a=1&b=2&c=3", function(error, text) { console.log(text); });
```

You can also use d3.xhr rather than d3.text directly if you want the full request object rather than just the responseText.

**Edit:** Updated to latest API.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much! I will keep an eye on the dev progress / docs to get informed about possible API changes.